# OK to pay for minyan?

Tags: transactions, minyan

If a minyan is needed and can't easily be found, is it OK to pay Jews to attend, who would not come otherwise?  And is a negotiation on the price seemly?

Comment: I have myself accepted money to attend a minyan that wouldn't otherwise have occurred.  These were mostly over Shabbat or a holiday.  I recall a story as well of a rabbi in Israel calling taxis to come to the shul, and when they arrived telling the drivers "run the meter. Stay here & daven & I will pay afterwards".  The drivers there didn't accept money, but it was clearly offered.

Comment: I don't doubt that it's done.  I am just wondering if it's halachically sanctioned.

Comment: The mishnah and the gemara call these people Batlanim, people paid to attend Mynianim

Comment: Does that mean the Talmud sanctions it or rejects it? Reference?

Comment: I read http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/2664-batlanim, which provides references. These apparently did more than just attend services -- they were paid for general community service.

Comment: I believe it was common practice in the shtetls, partly as a way of distributing tzedakah in an honourable way - ie as payment for services rendered.

Comment: See my answer, below. But, in considering this question, how is monetary payment any different from any other shul incentive? E.g. one way many shuls accomplish getting a minyan is by serving a fancy breakfast daily. It sounds like a similar idea. Their all incentives. I see nothing wrong with that.

Comment: It is a practice done at the time of the mishna and the gemara. Source Megila 3b ואמר ריב"ל כרך שאין בו עשרה בטלנין נדון ככפר מאי קמ"ל תנינא איזו היא עיר גדולה כל שיש בה עשרה בטלנין פחות מכאן הרי זה כפר כרך איצטריך ליה אע"ג דמיקלעי ליה מעלמא. Look at Rashi for instance

Comment: Maybe there is issue to pay them for Shabbos

Answer (score 1):

Several shuls in my neighborhood have been doing this for a while. I implicitly trust rabbis' halachic decisions, unless there's a strong compelling reason not to. I feel no need to inquire of my rabbi's reasoning as to why it is permissible, especially if he has been doing it for a few years. So, if you're willing to trust my rav on at least half the level as I do, then, yes, it's permissible.

As I know the nature of at least one person who attends this minyan and is paid (happens to be my son), it seems that negotiating the price is also permissible.

Comment: We don't know who your rabbi is so I don't know how we could trust him.

Comment: Is the logic explained anywhere?

Comment: I have heard it’s ok. But it was once joked that soon there  will be people being paid to sit shiva on someone else’s behalf.

Comment: @Daniel It's a given that all rabbis are automatically trustworthy, unless you or someone else has a valid reason to prove otherwise. The lack of this trust is what has consistently caused the demise of numerous Jewish communities. It would be meritorious if you and all readers would give every rabbi, regardless of your own personal knowledge of the person, benefit of doubt. Let's focus the doubt on the topic of the reasoning, not the rabbi, himself. Sound fair?

Comment: @DanielRoss Not much of a joke. I think some people have been doing this for a while. Mainly among Reform and Conservative.